# Не работает метод с переменным числом параметров

Tags: java, методы

Есть код из книжки по Java, набрал его, а он не хочет работать (закоменченная строка с TODO). Тут должен произойти вызов printArgCount(int...args), но в эклипсе подчёркивает и при запуске ругается: *"Unresolved compilation problem: The method printArgCount(Object[]) is ambiguous for the type DemoOverload"*

Версия джавы 7-я:

$java -version

**java version "1.7.0_60"**
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

Книжка врёт или ЧЯДНТ?

**Исходники:**

```
package chapter03;

public class DemoOverload {

    public static void printArgCount(Object... args){
        System.out.println("Object args: " + args.length);
    }

    public static void printArgCount(Integer[]...args){
        System.out.println("Integer[] args: "+args.length);
    }
    public static void printArgCount(int...args){
        System.out.println("int args: " + args.length);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] i = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        printArgCount(7, "No", true, null);
        printArgCount(i,i,i);
        printArgCount(i, 4, 71);
        printArgCount(i);
//      printArgCount(5,7);//TODO: непонятно почему не работает
    }
}
```

Comment: А в книжке случаем не написано чуть дальше, что в этой строке должна быть ошибка компиляции?

В JDK 8, кстати, отработает нормально.

Comment: @coutvv, и книжка не врет, и вы все делает так, только не дочитали следующий абзац, @a_gura - прав. `printArgCount(5,7);` может быть выполнен двумя методами: `printArgCount(Object...)` и `printArgCount(int...)`, компилятор не может выбрать, какой метод выполнять.

Comment: @a_gura, в книжке строго указано, что отработает (намеренные ошибки в исходниках демонстрируются и закомменчиваются), и в результате был "int args: 2". Правда, в качестве JDK в ней использовалась 6ая или 5-я версия.
@Yura Ivanov, если вы так считаете, можете объяснить, почему компилятор может выбрать между printArgCount(Object... args) и  public static void printArgCount(Integer[]...args), а вот между обжектом и примитивом в качестве параметров не может? Всё из-за примитовов? И опять же @a_gura сказал, что в 8-й компилится, почему? 0_о

Comment: @coutvv, это особенность компилятора. Ссылочные типы обрабатываются по одним правилам: ищется ближайший подходящий вариант. `Object...` является ближайшим по сравнению с `Integer[]...`. Метод с Integer[]... вызван никогда не будет при наличии метода с Object... (для единичного массива) и с Object[]... с несколькими массивами. Для примитивных типов правила другие: ближайшими являются оба метода и Object... с автобоксингом и int... без боксинга.  
Почему поведение изменено в 8 версии, не знаю, вероятно были причины.

Comment: Смысл данного урока, как я думаю, в том, чтобы показать, что Object... методы создавать надо с умом, а не на всякий случай типа дефолта.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, стоп стоп стоп!!! У меня ведь вызывается метод именно с Integer[]... !!! Чисто теоретически ваше объяснение логично и мне понятно, но на практике ведь не так! 
На этой строчке: printArgCount(i,i,i); выводит именно: Integer[] args: 3
И опять же повторюсь: в книге урок демонстрировал именно демонстрацию методов с переменным числом аргументов, смысл был только в этом, ей богу! Мне в принципе в этом плане было всё понятно, но как видите я нашёл такой забавный глюк и меня дико распирает почему работает именно так, а не иначе :D 
Пожалуйста помогите найти ответ!!!

Comment: @coutvv, все верно. вызывается `Integer[]...`, т.к. метода с `Object[]...` нету :)  
Про понятие "ближе" (most specific) можно почитать и сравнить в спецификации [JLS (Section: 15.12.2.5) - Java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) и [JLS (Section: 15.12.2.5) - Java8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) соответственно. 
Еще есть [5 Golden Rules of widening, boxing & varargs](http://www.coderanch.com/t/417622/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Golden-Rules-widening-boxing-varargs)